# Zxing not decoding 1D barcode 128 when it only holds one character

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing, code128

When I encode one character as a 1D code 128 barcode, i.e. 'F' or 'M', Zxing doesn't decode it. I first found this issue in my own app where I integrated the zxing source code. 
Then I checked the original Zxing standalone app as well, just to make sure it wasn't an issue with my integration, but also the standard Zxing app does not decode barcodes of 1 character length.

For example:

[image]

doesn't work.

But if the encoded string in the barcode is two or more characters long, i.e. 'AB', 'FF' or 'MM' it works fine. Why does it not work with 1 character length? A bug in zxing?

Comment: Indeed this don't work for me too +1. Confimed with HTC Desire HD. I also checked an older version. That was bug free.

Comment: @rekire: thanks, please upvote the bug on http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1103, I just filed the bug report

Comment: I don't know how to upvote there but I added a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a limitation built into the code in the past to reduce false positives. Based on your bug, it's been found to be no longer necessary and has been removed in the current svn head.

Comment: Yes I had disabled it purposely to avoid false positives but just turned it back on now as it's not a problem anymore.

Comment: @SeanOwen Thanks for the quick response and fix!